# How to implement a secure way to allow users to reset password via url?

Tags: web-applications, security, authentication

Password reset option should be given only if the link has come from that specific user's inbox and not from somewhere else. How to implement url in such a way that the required information i.e. Mailbox  can be obtained from the url? Facebook and Twitter like companies seem to have already implemented it. Any suggestions or ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

You put a cryptographically random, unguessable token on the password reset link that you send to the user's mailbox, and give them a time limit, expiring the link after that time limit has passed.  The token insures that it came from the right mailbox.

**Further Reading**
[Implementing web application self password reset mechanisms properly](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/1918)
[Forgot Password Cheat Sheet from OWASP](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Forgot_Password_Cheat_She)

Comment: what will happen if that user forwards that mail to someone else and that someone else clicks the link?

Comment: That's their problem, not yours.

Comment: whoever's problem might it be, what can be the solution to it?

Comment: You shouldn't solve that problem.  If you do, you're now taking responsibility for securing their PC for them.  You don't want that responsibility, trust me.  You're responsibility is solely to provide a secure channel for them to reset their password, not to eliminate *their* security breaches.

Comment: People access email from multiple devices (phone, pc(s), tablet, etc., so verifying the source is not feasible.  Email in of itself is not secure, so the link should lead them to an area that is secure and monitored as indicated by @Robert.